React.jsx: type is invalid, expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object | react-native-ui-datepicker
I have a component that uses the DateTimePicker from react-native-ui-datepicker library. While writing test case for it using jest it showing the following error
  Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
  
  Check the render method of `SingleDatePicker`.
      at onChange (/Users/**/DateTimePicker/SingleDatePicker.tsx:9:3)

  18 |       testID="single-date-picker"
  19 |     >
> 20 |       <DateTimePicker
     |       ^
  21 |         mode={'single'}
  22 |         date={date}
  23 |         onChange={onChange}

  at printWarning (node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js:87:30)
  at error (node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js:61:7)

My test case is,
import React from 'react';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import DatePicker from './DatePicker';
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react-native';

jest.mock('react-native-ui-datepicker', () => ({
  default: jest.fn(),
}));

const mockOnChange = jest.fn();

describe('Testing DatePicker', () => {
  const date = dayjs().format();
  it('Testing DatePicker', () => {
    render(
      <DatePicker type="single" date={date} onChange={mockOnChange} />
    );
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('single-date-picker')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

How to resolve this error?

What is the value of date

@Abe  const date = dayjs().format();

Mocking the react-native-ui-datepicker as mentioned below solved the issue for me.
jest.mock('react-native-ui-datepicker', () => {
  const Picker = () => <div />;
  return Picker;
});

